# How do add the missing datasource folder to jasper server

Tags: jasperserver

After installing Jasper Server 5.6 (without the sample reports, using bundled tomcat and db),and logging in with jasperadmin, when we select view->repository, there are only two folders: System Properties and Themes.

There is no Data source folder, and no way or option to add a datasource.

We tried uninstalling and re-installing, same problem.

Have tried googling - noone else seems to have this issue.

Any ideas how to get the datasource folder, or any alternative way to add a data source to jasper server if they have now removed the data source folder form the admin tool, and not updated the documentation?

Comment: I got the same problem with 6.0.1 which got resolved after installing sample data. Thanks for providing this work-around here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/843778/help-no-way-create-data-source